# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' -- Nothing online has worked so far

Tags: python, macos, pytorch

Update: Pretty sure I'm having trouble with circular imports. I don't full understand it. I named a file random.py :/ and now my matplotlib doesn't work, but when I delete random.py and the .pyc file, torch runs fine. So I can get torch to work, but matplotlib won't work. If it helps, I use matplotlib and torch in the same file like always, and the file that this all started with used both those libraries.

I'm really lost on the error I'm getting. I've been using python for a while and pytorch for a month with no problems, however, this afternoon, my programs just stopped running. I use vim and installed everything with pip.

Everything is up to date--I've checked and rechecked. I uninstalled pytorch then reinstalled. Same with torchvision and torchaudio. First I was getting an error with numpy, so I updated that, but it just gave me a new import error with torch. When I ran a file with torch imported, a **pychache** directory would appear in the directory I ran the file in -- I don't know what this means. However, now that I've updated numpy, it stopped appearing. Also, torch doesn't work throughout my entire system, I've tried in a lot of different directories.

Nothing online has helped me so far after a couple hours of searching, so I'm lost here. If anyone can explain what's going on and why it happened so randomly, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/****/Coding/python/DeepLearningCourse/week4/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Edit2: I've been playing around some more and I used pip3 to install torch torchvision and torchaudio. It's still not working but I get a new traceback and the **pycache** directory appears again. What's the difference between pip and pip3 in this regard?

Traceback after installing with pip3. This traceback is the same whether I use python filename.py vs python3 filename.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/****/Coding/python/DeepLearningCourse/week4/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ._utils_internal import get_file_path, prepare_multiprocessing_environment, \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils_internal.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/Users/****/Coding/python/DeepLearningCourse/week4/random.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch.nn as nn
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .modules import *  # noqa: F403
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .module import Module
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..parameter import Parameter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parameter.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Parameter(torch.Tensor):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Edit3: I deleted the small file I was testing on and now torch works, but marplotlib doesn't.... :|

Comment: Please include the full traceback error and relevant parts of your code.  You need to specify the steps clearly.

Comment: @ewong sorry... updated my post. The code just had "import torch" and then I created an object from that library. This occurs with any file that has "import torch" though

Comment: I find this question very hard to follow. Perhaps, instead of appending edits to the original question, you want to  re-write it completely to reflect the current state of the issue.

Comment: start your program with `python -v ...` it will print a lot of debug information about where it looks for the different modules. This might help you debug this issue.

Comment: @Shai when I run that I get this error for the matplotlib import (sorry for the formatting)`line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
`

Comment: @Shai , never mind, I figured it out! When I was trying to fix the circular imports problem, I updated everything because I thought that might be the problem I was running into. I downloaded python 3.9 in the process. This made Matplotlib freak out because it was in 3.7 or something (I dont really understand this), so pip uninstall/install wasn't helping, which is what I usually use. So I had two import errors for two different reasons with the same error message :|. I had to delete the pyc file for the circular imports and uninstall/install Matplotlib with pip3 instead of pip.